# Time length of key pressed down

Tags: javascript

Is is possible to find out the time of how long a key is pressed down?
I want to call a function after the ctrl key is pressed for one second.

Comment: what have you tried ? We arent here for writing a code for you. Checkout `onkeydown` `onkeyup` and `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var timeout;

document.onkeydown = function() {
    if (!timeout) {
        timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
            timeout = null;
            alert("pressed for a second");
        }, 1000);
    }
}

document.onkeyup = function() {
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

You just have to add the check whether or not it's the CTRL key that is pressed (in both event handlers of course.)

Comment: thanks after sleeping for a night i came up with the same solution